# Send UDP datagram from browser using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I need to be able to send an UDP datagram to a remote server.
Main purpose is for the request to send authentication data to the server and to open an UDP port on the gateway so it can receive a video stream on that port.

Is there some possible way to achieve this?
I've searched a lot and I read that javascript wouldn't allow that because of security issues which I fully understand.

Thank you

Comment: read WebRTC, http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned it's impossible with native browser technologies. JavaScript can not use any transport protocols directly. The only feasible way I know is to use Flash. You can find examples in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907041/is-it-possible-to-use-udp-in-flash-actionscript).

Comment: Well as mentioned in that same discussion this is only possible with AIR on desktop environments. Flash in a web browser cannot use UDP for security reasons. Do you think it would be possible using a Java applet? wouldn't there be security limitations?